# Mostrar páginas do site no Google

Tags: wordpress, seo, plugin-wordpress, google

Estou tentando mostrar um "mapa" do site no Google quando pesquisado, porém não estou obtendo sucesso.

Utilizando o plugin `Yoast SEO`, configurei todas as páginas do site, porém não obtive sucesso. Ao pesquisar o site no Google, aparece apenas a página inicial, sem mostrar as outras.

Tentei também criar o arquivo sitemap.xml e fazer o upload no servidor manualmente e posteriormente indexá-lo ao Search Console, porém ainda não obtive sucesso.

A imagem abaixo representa o que estou tentando como resultado:

[image: Imagem exemplo]

Answer (score 4):

Isto se chama sitelinks e eles são renderizados automaticamente pelo `Google`, para que isso possa funcionar corretamente é necessário acessar o painel `Google Web Master Tools` e fazer a integração do serviço do site em questão veja como fazer [aqui](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6337256?hl=pt-BR).

Também é importante a criação do sitemap e do arquivo robots.txt é nele que o google irá verificar possíveis bloqueios então precisa estar bem configurado, veja como testar seu arquivo e como escrever nele [aqui](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=pt-BR).

Outra coisa é ter um site fluido e sem muito redirecionamento interno, páginas com quebra gerando erro como `404` e `403` deixam seu site em má colocação nos resultados na pesquisa.

> Para finalizar `sitelinks`

Eles serão criados dinamicamente pelo google conforme indice de pesquisa da página e ligação entre elas, mas caso comecem aparecer páginas que não gostaria nesta secção só acessar o `google web master tools` e configurar o que deve aparecer e o que não deve.

Então não espere que esta lista de `sitelinks` aparece de imediato uma vez que os servidores do google precisam propagar essas informações entre eles e seu site precisa ter algumas buscar no serviço para que seja criado estes logs.